# How to identify the pixels with the highest activation from four or more grayscale images and save as the final heatmap?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, bitwise-operators

I have four attention maps, each of dimension 217 x 217 and in the form of array of float64. I need to perform an operation using these attention maps and save the final attention map where only the pixels with the highest activations are present. A custom function is needed in this regard. Attached are the heatmaps:

[image: heatmap4.png]
[image: heatmap3.png]
[image: heatmap2.png]
[image: heatmap1.png]

The starter code is here:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image

im1 = np.array(Image.open("heatmap1.png").convert('L'))
im2 = np.array(Image.open("heatmap2.png").convert('L'))
im3 = np.array(Image.open("heatmap3.png").convert('L'))
im4 = np.array(Image.open("heatmap4.png").convert('L'))

#compute to save only the pixels with the highest activation

#save final heatmap as a PNG file
cv2.imwrite("final_heatmap.png", bitwise_AND)
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Yes, I want the pixelwise maximum to be present in the final image.

Comment: stack them, then np.max(axis=...)

Comment: why does the code in your question mention "bitwise and"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the pixelwise maximum between two images, use `np.maximum(im1, im2)`. The bitwise logical AND gives the maximum only for Boolean values, but does not generalize to gray-scale values.

To find the pixelwise maximum across four images, use a pyramidal scheme with pairwise operators:

```py
out1 = np.maximum(im1, im2)
out2 = np.maximum(im3, im4)
out = np.maximum(out1, out2)
```

You can do the above a bit more efficiently if you are willing to overwrite inputs:

```py
np.maximum(im1, im2, out=im1)
np.maximum(im3, im4, out=im3)
np.maximum(im1, im3, out=im1)  # im1 now has the result
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the numpy's built-in function

```
logical_and
bitwise_or
bitwise_xor
binary_repr
```

an example usage is like following

```
np.bitwise_and(arr1, arr2)
```

Comment: A working script with the attached images would be great.